# Cycling visibility in orgmode headings

Tags: org-mode

When cycling visibility of a subtree using TAB, subtrees will open increasingly showing more subheadings, one at a time. However, when I cycle a buffer globally using S-TAB, their contents are shown, which feels like the wrong thing to do.

This is my tree:

```
* heading 1
** subheading 1.1
*** subheading 1.1.1
*** subheading 1.1.2
** subheading 1.2
* heading 2
** subheading 2.1
*** subheading 2.1.1
* heading 3
```

When all collapsed, they look like this:

```
* heading 1
* heading 2
* heading 3
```

When I do S-TAB they all open to their most inner subheading:

```
* heading 1
** subheading 1.1
*** subheading 1.1.1
*** subheading 1.1.2
** subheading 1.2
* heading 2
** subheading 2.1
*** subheading 2.1.1
* heading 3
```

I would want first to show the immediate level, like this, before showing all the sub-subheadings.

```
* heading 1
** subheading 1.1
** subheading 1.2
* heading 2
** subheading 2.1
* heading 3
```

Any way to do this?

Thank you,
EG

Comment: The docstring of the function invoked with Shift-Tab `org-shifttab` says `When ARG is a numeric prefix, show contents of this level.` So if you do `C-u 2 S-TAB` it shows up to level 2 headings. Is that good enough? Or do you want to modify the behavior of the function? There is also `org-overview` (show top-level headings) and `org-content` (show all headings without content, it's possible to use `C-u 2 M-x org-content` as well).

Comment: Thanks, I did not know of that prefixed behaviour. Thank you! Question #1: I understand that org-content would be equal to doing C-u (highest number) S-TAB. Question #2: C-u 2 M-x org-content is equal to C-u 2 S-TAB?. Thank you

Comment: I would also like something like this, so that `S-TAB` cycles "one step" at a time: -> TOP LEVEL HEADINGS -> SECOND LEVELS -> THIRD LEVELS -> … -> SHOW ALL

Comment: Actually, S-TAB does not show second levels only, it shows directly org-overview, which means, all top-level headings.